# C# creating common instance

Tags: c#, instance

My question is why does this line - `ThreadTest tt = new ThreadTest();` in below example create a common instance not a separate instance. Please advise, thanks!

```
class ThreadTest
{
  bool done;

  static void Main()
  {
    ThreadTest tt = new ThreadTest();   // Create a common instance
    new Thread (tt.Go).Start();
    tt.Go();
  }

  // Note that Go is now an instance method
  void Go() 
  {
     if (!done) { done = true; Console.WriteLine ("Done"); }
  }
}
```

EDIT:
The example is from http://www.albahari.com/threading/#_Introduction which demonstrates how to share data between threads.

EDIT2:
My question is exactly why "the instance is common to both threads"

Comment: What is `ThreadTest`? I can't find such a class in the Framework.

Comment: @Bobby: Uhm, the code in the question declares it.

Comment: What do you mean by "common instance" ? There's only one call to the constructor, so there is only one instance of ThreadTest

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is unclear what you mean by “common instance”, but the constructor definitely creates a new instance. The `Go` method is executed twice, once in the new thread and once in the main thread.

Maybe what the author of the code meant is that the instance is common to both threads, because both threads call the `Go` method on the same instance.

<sup><sub>The inside of the `Go` method has a race condition. It may unpredictably print “Done” twice.</sub></sup>

Comment: your guess is right. However, my question is exactly why "the instance is common to both threads".

Comment: Because you’re creating only one and using it twice.

Comment: Ah, I thought it was like
new Thread (tt.Go).Start();   
Go();

Comment: @Stan Even if you try to execute your code: new Thread(tt.Go).Start(); Go(); it won't compile. You can not call just Go() without an instance (https://dotnetfiddle.net/L5flfO -> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property ThreadTest.Go()), unless method is declared static.

Comment: Digging a little deeper into the statement `threads share data if they have a common reference to the same object instance`, does this necessarily mean the threads that are executing in parallel execute instructions from the same object instance's stack memory? It follows that if one thread were scheduled more frequently than the other, a race condition may occur.

Comment: @MinhTran Object instances use heap memory, not stack. Threads do not share stack memory. But yes, if the threads access the same object, they access the same heap memory, which leads to race conditions. Heap memory is not owned by any threads but shared by all of them.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that both calls to `tt.Go` share the 'done' variable, then that will of course happen.  You are calling a method on the same object, just that one happens in the main thread, and one happens in a separate thread.

You only ever create one instance of ThreadTest, but call Go twice, so both calls have to happen on the same object!

Answer (score 1):

6 years later and I'm here because I read the same section of that book. The example in the book immediately previous to the one you mentioned shows (a static) .Go being executed on an anonymous new thread, and then again separately in the local context.

```
new Thread (Go).Start();
Go();
```

The example in your question first creates an instance of the TT and also changes .Go from being a static method to an instance method.

```
ThreadTest tt = new ThreadTest();
new Thread (tt.Go).Start();
tt.Go();
```

So now when .Go is sent to the new thread for execution, what is getting sent is tt's copy of the method (instead of a static .Go method), which is also what gets executed locally immediately afterwards on line 3. Since both executions of .Go belong to tt, they also use tt's copy of `done`. Afaik, this is why the author calls this data "common", because it can now be accessed by both threads.

Aside: I'm still shaky on several aspects of threading myself. One mystery to me is what exactly happens to tt when `new Thread (tt.Go).Start();` executes... tt was instantiated in the initial thread, but it now lives in both? Does byref/byval apply here or is something else going on? Is it more accurate to say that the tt object doesn't actually 'live' or 'belong to' either thread, but rather on the heap, and therefore both threads should have access to it?

Comment: Object ownership is more of a logical distinction for the programmer than a technical one. The object exists (lives) on the heap and has no 'owner'. It's shared because in passing `tt.Go` to the new thread, it captures the `tt` instance, so the new thread has a reference to `tt` which ensures it is kept alive; the main thread also has a reference to `tt`. This, in effect, gives shared data. The object lives while any reference exists to it -- it doesn't matter which thread or threads.